# Sending image from html canvas to flask python not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a flask app with html and js. It takes image from webcam, stores in html canvas, and then convert canvas to data url and send it to flask via ajax. I than use base64 to decode the data and read it with cv2 imdecode.

The problem I am having is my python code of the image is not executing at all. My webpage loads, everything works but when I take the pic, nothing happens.

Also another thing is that the `console.log` function of JS doesn't work when html is rendered in flask, so I don't know if something is wrong with my JS code.

Can you please look at my html as well as python code to tell me where I am going wrong? I am sure that the python function supposed to be called on the url of ajax is not called.

This is my js for sending the ajax:

```js
//Function called on pressing a html button
function takePic() {

  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//video is the video element in html which is recieving live data from webcam

  var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(imgURL);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://url/take_pic", //I have doubt about this url, not sure if something specific must come before "/take_pic"
    data: imgURL,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        alert('Your file was successfully uploaded!');
      } else {
        alert('There was an error uploading your file!');
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('There was an error uploading your file!');
    }
  }).done(function() {
    console.log("Sent");
  });

}
```

I have question about the url parameter in ajax, I think something specific must come before that`"/take_pic"`, not just `"https://url"`.

Here is my python:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import numpy as np
import cv2
import re
import base64

import io

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="flask templates")

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('live webcam and capture.html')

@app.route('/take_pic',methods=["POST"])
def disp_pic():
    data = request.data
    encoded_data = data.split(',')[1]
    nparr = np.fromstring(encoded_data.decode('base64'), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow(img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Yeah the URL should probably be `http://localhost:5000/take_pic`

Comment: Nothing in Flask can disable the console. Are you certain your are actually reaching the `console.log` lines? Is there an AJAX network request being sent from the browser? You could try to use your browser's debugger to see if your code is actually being executed.

Comment: @barro32: no, URLs can be relative, just a path would suffice.

Comment: But Flask runs on `localhost:5000` by default, right? They're trying to `POST` to `http://url/take_pic` from the JS

Comment: @Shantanu when you say your webpage loads, what URL are you going to in the browser?

Comment: @barro32 I open it from the local host link that is generated o running the python code. And about that console.log, none of the console logs appear in inspection mode, not even errors in js. But other js code, which draws the image into canvas work fine, I can the the image in the webpage.

Comment: I think the URL you POST to should be the same as that localhost URL you use in the browser but with `/take_pic` on the end.
Can you show the JS code used to trigger `takePic()`

Comment: @barro32 takePic() is triggered using a button onclick event, not JS. I changed the url, now it is calling the python function, but still no console logs and it is giving error in the split function that data is not str,

Comment: I presume you've already created the `canvas` and `ctx` outside of `takePic()`? Can you put a `console.log('takePic start')` on the first line of `takePic()` and see if that works?

Comment: @barro32 yes, an empty canvas is in the html. I already tried putting console.log there before posting the question, it doesn't work. Also, there were some errors in JS which didn't show up in console on running the code. Another issue is that flask gets stuck on sending the POST request.

Comment: @barro32 i just realised that flask is not responding to any of the ajax request ii give from JS, not GET nor POST.. why is that happening?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just created new python and html files and put similar code and now it is working. Don't know the exact cause of error but both the codes are same.

Comment: Could you give more info on that?